# TFS checkout failing in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, tfs, checkout

TFS checkout is failing in Jenkins. It is giving below error. Previously It worked fine,but from past 4 days I am getting this error. Few file are checking out and getting this error:

> FATAL: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.versioncontrol.exceptions.VersionControlException:
>   com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TECoreException: Server was unable
>   to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object. com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.exceptions.SOAPFault: Server
>   was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

I have tried with different versions of TFS plugins. Currently I have installed  TFS 5.142 version  and Jenkins version 2.176.2

Comment: Did you change any setting in both TFS or Jenkins side? Please also check the network if you are behind a proxy or not. Try to [clear TFS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/) which may do the trick.

Comment: TFS is installed in another server and I did not change anything in TFS side. I have tried with clearing cache and ran Jenkins  build to checkout the code. Now the error is intermittent. Sometimes Jenkins build is success with checkout few files ,sometime it is success with checkout zero files and sometimes it is throwing same error again

Comment: Hi Vinutna, sorry for later reply. Looks like not related to TFS side. Especially for this kind of probability problems.  Sometimes Jenkins build is success with checkout few files ,sometime it is success with checkout zero files. Could this related to network such as packet loss rate of a network or something else? Instead of using Jenkins build, you could use some other build such as TFS own build  or  API to check out code. If this works, it may related to Jenkins build side.